# Configure alias directory for Grunt connect server

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, node.js-connect

I have some folders in my source that I want to serve up using connect via a grunt task. My folder structure is as follows...

- /
- /src

  - index.jade
  - /styles

    - main.css
- /dist

  - index.html
- /docs

  - index.html

My grunt configuration looks something like this...

```
grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 8080,
            hostname: '0.0.0.0',
            livereload: 35729
        },
        app: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static(require('path').resolve(pkg.paths.dist)),
                        connect.static(require('path').resolve(pkg.paths.src)),
                        connect.static(require('path').resolve(pkg.paths.docs))
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
    }
})
```

Firing up a server, and visiting `http://localhost:8080/` will give me the `index.html` file from `dist` - which has been compiled from `index.jade`, which refers to `main.css` which is dutifully served up from `src`. This is all excellent, and works great.

Now I want to access the `index.html` file from `docs`, but on an aliased url - so `http://localhost:8080/mycustomurl`. I don't want to put my docs in a sub-folder, I just want to configure connect to serve urls matching `mycustomurl` from the `docs` directory.

How can I modify my configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom middleware. `middleware` option expects a function that returns an array of middlewares.

```
custom_middleware: {
  options: {
    middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
      return [connect.static(require('path').resolve(pkg.paths.dist)),
              connect.static(require('path').resolve(pkg.paths.src)),
              function (req, res, next) {
                if (req.url !== '/custom/url') {
                  next();
                  return;
                }
                // res.sendFile(pkg.paths.docs + '/index.html');
                // you can access the "anything.html" by parsing the req.url
                var file = req.url.split('/');
                file = file[file.length-1];
                res.sendFile(pkg.paths.docs + file);
              }
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

For more configuration options see [example Gruntfile](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/blob/master/Gruntfile.js).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want to serve just one file from the new route, I want to proxy anything matching a pattern to be served from a different folder.

Comment: what, did you actually try my solution, this is not serving one file, there is three middlewares here, and the third one is proxy to a different folder matching '/custom/url' pattern. @BillyMoon

Comment: I want that a request to `/custom/url/anything.html` is served as the file `anything.html` in the `docs` folder - not always to serve `index.html`.

Comment: @BillyMoon, that's easy enough, just parse the `req.url`, see my edit please, and note I haven't tested how to parse the `req.url` it might need some fix, try and suit yourself. Finally accept the answer ;).

Comment: I up-voted your answer, but still not content - sorry. Is there not a way to somehow still use a `connect.static` within the custom function - to avoid all the manual parsing of urls, setting of headers, loading files etc... so if matches custom url, then serve using connect static from custom dir, else go to next. Is that do-able?

Comment: @user3995789 That's not how this works. The OP wants an answer for something that you haven't provided, as do I.
There's more to SO than reputation, please respect that.

Comment: Why the repetition of `require("path")`?